# Changing file extensions

Tags: java, windows, windows-8

I am doing some algorithmic problems on the website USACO, and for every submission they want us to make two files for input and output to test values. So if the problem was called "test", they would want users to make the files "test.in" and "test.out" which requires them to change their extensions to ".out" and ".in". How do I change their extensions from ".txt" to ".in" or ".out"?

Note: I am using Windows 8

Thank you

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Need a LOT more information. What language? What library/framework? Which version of Windows? What have you already attempted?

Comment: I am using Java with the Eclipse compiler. And I have attempted to make files in Eclipse but it turns into .txt. I am using the file reader library in Java.

Comment: Seems more like a Java question than a Windows 8 one. While I don't know Java - there must be some `move` or `rename` method. Maybe the [`File.renameTo()`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/RenameafileinJava.htm) method?

Answer (score 0):

**To make Java read files in Eclipse**

One must make sure that the words typed in the code and in the name of the file match each other. 
For example: The file referenced in must exist.
`BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.in"));` 
Also, you have to make the file under the project folder (in Eclipse or manually in Windows Explorer) because that folder is the directory at for that code, and if it is not in the folder the code will not be able to read it. You can also right-click the project to import files into the folder.

My reference: Trial and Error

http://www.coderanch.com/t/439615/java-io/java/Eclipse-won-read-text-file